# How to show $a_n = \frac{n+1}{n-1}$ is strictly decreasing by induction?

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

I can show this fact otherwise, but I can't seem to figure out the simple algebra to prove it by induction...Could someone provide a hint? I just need a push in the right direction. It seems too simple to be this difficult.

(Please don't give me the answer, just a hint will do).

Comment: If you can prove it by other means, then you necessarily can prove it by induction. Just ignore the induction hypothesis and prove it the way you know to finalize the induction.

Comment: Induction is a profoundly unnatural way to prove the result. I don’t see a genuine induction argument: they all reduce to the trick that @GitGud describes. That is, they’re all direct proofs with an unnecessary base case and unused induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the easy way. Write

$$a_n = \frac{n+1}{n-1} = \frac{n-1 + 2}{n-1} = 1 + \frac{2}{n-1}.$$

Then use induction to show that $2/(n-1)$ is decreasing and the hence $a_n$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 3):

Not a proof by induction but it never hurs to notice

$$a_n = \frac{n+1}{n-1}$$
$$a_{n+1} = \frac{(n+1)+1}{(n+1)-1}= \frac{n+2}{n}$$

Notice that
$$n^2+n-2 \lt n^2+n$$
$$(n+2)(n-1) \lt n(n+1)$$

$$\frac{n+2}{n} \lt\frac{n+1}{n-1}$$
$$a_{n+1}\lt a_n$$

Answer (score 2):

Proof by induction is as follows:

Base step:  Show the statement is true for the smallest value of n that matters.  In your case, I'm guessing the smallest n is 2?

Inductive Step:  show that if the statement is true for some n then it is true for n+1.

By induction, your proof is complete.

It's easy to show that it's true for the base step.  $a_2=3$.  $a_3=\frac{4}{2}=2$.  And $2<3$.

Can you do the inductive step?

Comment: But can you prove that $2 < 3$ by induction?

Comment: 2 < 3 is an axiom of the real numbers.  There is no proof for this; it just is.  It's a consequence of the fact that the real numbers are ordered.

Comment: Joke. Besides, to prove that 2 < 3, we have to start with the Peano axioms, define 2=succ(1) and 3=succ(2), and define the "<" predicate in terms of succ.

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{array}\\
a_n-a_{n+1}
&=\frac{n+1}{n-1}-\frac{n+2}{n}\\
&=\frac{(n+1)n-(n+2)(n-1)}{(n-1)n}\\
&=\frac{n^2+n-(n^2+n-2}{(n-1)n}\\
&=\frac{2}{(n-1)n}\\
&> 0\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: And all that is left to show here is the base step.

Comment: This is not, however, a proof by induction.

Comment: You don't need a base step. This shows directly that $a_n > a_{n+1}$. Of course, you could use the equality to make a proof by induction.

Comment: The induction is there "hidding":  to show that $\;\frac2{n(n-1)} >0\;$ for $\;n>1\;$ . +1